# Issue with Audio Playback in ARSCNView Scene

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm currently working on an AR app using ARKit and SceneKit, and I've encountered an issue with audio playback in my ViewController class. I have a SCNNode that represents a rotating and moving box in my ARSCNView. I want to add audio playback to this node using the SCNAudioPlayer.

I've set up the audio source and added it to the SCNNode using the addAudioPlayer method, but for some reason, the audio doesn't seem to play during the scene execution. I've made sure that the audio file (sample_audio.mp3) is in the correct location and that the SCNAudioSource is correctly initialized and loaded.

I've included a simplified version of my code below:

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import SnapKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Property
    
    // MARK: - execute
    private func execute() {
        action_example1()
    }
    
    // MARK: - UIComponents
    private lazy var arSceneView: ARSCNView = {
        $0.delegate = self
        $0.showsStatistics = true
        return $0
    }(ARSCNView())
}

extension ViewController {
    func action_example1() {
        let scene = SCNScene()
        arSceneView.scene = scene

        let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0.1)
        
        var boxNode = SCNNode()
        boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
        boxNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -5)
        
        let material = SCNMaterial()
//        material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(resource: .pyramidFull)
        
        boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = material
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

        let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: .pi, z: 0, duration: 2)
        let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(0, 0, +10), duration: 2)
        let sequenceAction = SCNAction.sequence([rotateAction, moveAction])
        let repeatAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(sequenceAction)
        
        
        let audioSource = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "sample_audio.mp3")!
        audioSource.loops = true
        boxNode.runAction(SCNAction.playAudio(audioSource, waitForCompletion: false))
        audioSource.load()
        
        
        boxNode.runAction(repeatAction)
    }
}

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    // MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate
    
/*
    // Override to create and configure nodes for anchors added to the view's session.
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        print(#function)
        let node = SCNNode()
        
        return node
    }
*/
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // Present an error message to the user
        print(#function)
        
    }
    
    func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay
        print(#function)
    }
    
    func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

I've taken the following steps to address the audio playback issue:

Created a new SCNAudioSource instance with the audio file name (sample_audio.mp3) and set the loops property to true.
Loaded the audio source using the load() method to ensure it's ready for playback.
Added the SCNAudioPlayer to the SCNNode using the addAudioPlayer method.
I expected that with these steps, the audio file would play continuously as the SCNNode animates within the ARSCNView scene. However, despite these efforts, the audio doesn't appear to be playing during the scene execution.

Is there something I might be overlooking or an additional configuration required to enable successful audio playback within this ARSCNView scene?

Answer (score 1):

as a quick solution to your issue you might consider this "Workaround":

instead of adding the Audio Player like this `boxNode.addAudioPlayer(SCNAudioPlayer(source: audioSource))`

Try something like that - add an additional Action to the Node:

```
boxNode.runAction(SCNAction.playAudio(audioSource, waitForCompletion: false))
```

You also might consider to use the `AVFoundation` Framework and use (as a simplified example):

```
do { soundSession = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url) } catch { print(error) }
```

and then:

```
soundSession.volume = defaultVolume
soundSession.numberOfLoops = numberOfLoops // -1 for endless looping, 0 for once
soundSession.currentTime = 0.0
soundSession.play()
```

**PS: Also make sure to access the MP3 file correctly: i.Ex. like this:**

```
SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "art.scnassets/soundeffects/Blastwave_FX_BasketballBounce_AP1.1290.wav")!
```

Hope I could give some guidance.

PS: almost everything in Swift is case sensitive:
correct your code like so:

```
let audioSource = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "sample_audio.MP3")!
```

(turned the .mp3 extension to .MP3) then it works.

Comment: I appreciate the response and suggestions provided so far. Despite implementing the recommended changes, the audio playback issue still persists in my ARSCNView scene. To provide a more comprehensive understanding of my implementation, I've included the full code snippet for the ViewController class update: Main Content of the Text

Comment: Can you provide me your project as a download? I'll check on it.

Comment: Regarding your code issue on Stack Overflow, I've made several attempts to assist, but unfortunately, success has eluded me so far.

I've created a code snippet that might be helpful. You can find it here: [ https://file2.me/d/2rana2 ].

Please review it and incorporate it into your project as needed. If you encounter any roadblocks, feel free to ask for further guidance.

Wishing you the best in resolving this. Good luck!

Comment: please check the PS section in my answer I added at the bottom.

Comment: did you have some success with my updated answer?